# Using Python Dictionary to identify the what function to use for file transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm currently attempting to use Python Dictionary to identify the file type and output the function needed to transform a spreadsheet into a pandas dataframe.

It actually works but except when I attempt to upload a file with **.csv** extension, I'm getting: **XLRDError**

Where I only saved a copy of the **.xlsx** file that is working into **.csv**

there a better practice for this one? (without using "if")

**Stuff.py**

```
def execute(file_path):

    read_map = {"xls": pd.read_excel, "xlsm": pd.read_excel, "xlsx": pd.read_excel,
                "csv": pd.read_csv}

    get_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1].lower()[1:]

    assert get_extension in read_map
    assert os.path.isfile(file_path)

    #reads convert into DataFrame
    read_function = read_map[get_extension]
    df = read_function(file_path)

    return df
```

**Fetch.py**

```
import Stuff as s

UPLOAD_DIR = "/"

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():

     if request.method == "POST":

           #get data
           data = request.files["data_file"]

           filename = secure_filename(data.filename)
           abs_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIR, filename)

           #save the data
           data.save(abs_path)

           output_data = s.execute(abs_path)
```

Comment: Could you please post the full stacktrace? Your code looks ok and that XLRDError is either a pointer that the file is corrupt or that you are using an old xlrd version

Comment: Sure, hold on, I'll update the post

Comment: @OcasoProtal, done updating the post

Comment: And where is the complete error message? As I said, your code looks fine at a first glance and the use of the dictionary for the functions is good, but we need the exact error message.